# Graphs for representing performance of machine learning classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, performance, metric, roc

Can any please guide about how many types of the graph other than ROC can be plotted to represent the performance of the machine learning classifier?

Comment: Accuracy or performance?

Comment: @sentence my bad, its performance.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are:

1. Precision-Recall Curve
2. ROC Curve

Then, you can plot other features of the model to get insights about generalization, learning process, overfitting/underfitting, like accuracy vs epochs, loss versus epochs, to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful "graph" is the Validation curve. This will show you the difference between your training curve and you testing curve.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-validation-curve-py